# How to get previous finger position in Leap Motion

Tags: processing, leap-motion

Im a beginner at Leap Motion. I am wondering how to get the previous finger position of my hand. I am basically looking for the equivalent of `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` from Processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Leap Motion, but assuming you have access to the current finger position, you could always track the previous position yourself. In Processing it would look something like this:

```java
int previousMouseX;
int previousMouseY;

void draw(){

  line(previousMouseX, previousMouseY, mouseX, mouseY);

  previousMouseX = mouseX;
  previouseMouseY = mouseY;
}
```

This is pretty much what Processing is doing for you with the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables.